# different results because of new line character

Tags: c++

I wrote below program that prints even numbers from 100 to 1000 but when i change `cout<<i<<" ";` with `cout<<i<<"\n";` it starts from **410** not **100**.

Why they have different results?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k;
    for(int i=100;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        k=i%2;
        if(k==0)
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure and nothing to do with the size of the terminals buffer?

Comment: more than  likely your console only goes 590 lines back.  You can test this by putting `std::cout << "start of main\n";` as the first line in `main`.  If you do not see it then you know you can't go that far back in the output.

Comment: What is the "it" that you are referring to? The output of the program? The display on your screen? The contents of the file you redirected output to? Or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are still getting correct output. But due to the limited size of your output console, you are unable to see the top 200 or so entries.